# How to add quotes around a string of text and a comma

Tags: sql, razorsql

I just started using sql and I have a long list of emails in the following format

```
xy@gmail.com
jkk@gmail.com
ghgh@gmail.com
```

I need to add quotes around each email and a comma after the end quote with a result like the following

```
'xy@gmail.com',
'jkk@gmail.com',
'ghgh@gmail.com',
```

I have seen a function in razorsql which could do this automatically, can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting your SQL statement like this to get the output you're after:

```
SELECT '''' + emailAddress + ''',' FROM users
```